# Build rabbitmq from source

Tags: python, erlang, makefile, rabbitmq

I try to build rabbitmq-server-2.4.1 from source. But get error:

```
make
python codegen.py body codegen/amqp-rabbitmq-0.9.1.json
src/rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1.erl
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "codegen.py", line 492, in <module>
   "body": generateErl})
 File "codegen/amqp_codegen.py", line 283, in do_main_dict
   execute(funcDict[function], sources, dest)
 File "codegen/amqp_codegen.py", line 262, in execute
   fn(amqp_specs)
 File "codegen.py", line 485, in generateErl
   genErl(AmqpSpec(specPath))
 File "codegen/amqp_codegen.py", line 140, in __init__
   self.major = self.spec['major-version']
KeyError: 'major-version'
make: *** No rule to make target `deps.mk', needed by
`ebin/bpqueue.beam'.  Stop.
```

I use python 2.7.1

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be the python version.
I was able to **compile and install rabbitMQ 2.4.1 using python 2.6.2.**

If you use Solaris and use pkgutil, the command to get python 2.6.2 would be

```
# My version of Sun OS (for comparison)
$ uname -a 
SunOS dev21 5.10 Generic_141445-09 i86pc i386 i86pc 

# install python 2.6.2
$ sudo pkgutil --install python-2.6.2,REV=2009.08.06
```

NOTE: I still saw these error messages during *make*.  The build of rabbitMQ 2.4.1 still succeeded.

```
$ make
/bin/sh: python2.5: not found
python codegen.py body codegen/amqp-rabbitmq-0.9.1.json src/rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1.erl 
...
```